# REST API: How to get error details of Field Validation errors, SPListDataValidationException

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, pnpjs, nodejs

I am using pnpjs to add items to a list like so:

```
this.spClient.web.lists.getByTitle(this.spList).items.add(requestList);
```

If `requestList` has items that do not pass column validation of the Sharepoint list I receive an exception with only a very generic error message:

```
{"odata.error": {
     "code": "-2130575163,Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListDataValidationException",
     "message": {
         "lang": "en-US",
         "value": "List data validation failed."
      }
}}
```

**How can I retrieve the information which fields failed validation?**

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest#working-with-list-items-by-using-rest suggests the information should be available and if I try to add such an erroneous element manually in Sharepoint itself the form marks the errors in red.

Answer (score 0):

Go into the network tab in Chrome dev tools (or else use Fiddler), find the REST call and inspect the raw response from the server. For 400-type errors you'll typically see a more detailed description of the error.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I get a 500 error and that is an exception. Checking with Fiddler the response doesn't contain anything more than what I show in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the item using PnPjs like this:

```
private PnPAddItem():void
{
  sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Jerry").items.add({
    Title: "NewItemAddedTitle"
  }).then((iar: ItemAddResult) => {
    console.log(iar);
});

}
```

You can console.log(iar) response in the console to see which field failed validation and you could also check the Network tab to see reponse status and request details:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work. I get a 500 response, which throws an exception. So the `then` part isn't taken at all. try/catch doesn't lead to more than what I showed in my question. But thanks for the `then`, I hadn't thought of it.

Comment: Can you please create a new list and then just add a item with default Title field to see if it works ? As the script above won't have problem in my side.

Comment: Sorry, I can't test this right now. I am sure the `then` branch will be taken if there is no error. The point here is a field that fails column validation. In that case I get a javascript exception which I can handle with try/catch of course. But there is only generic information in the exception itself.

Comment: Please test if you have time and updates :)

Comment: Could you elaborate what this test is supposed to show? I don't have any problem with adding a list item. It is only if there is a validation for a certain field and that validation indicates a problem with the data provided that I don't get sufficient information. So how should updating trivial Title field provide any insight?

Comment: So have you checked the validation settings in your field settings ? In my side, I have no issue just working...

Comment: Yes, the validations work fine. Like a field must match a certain RE or a date to be not more than 180 days in the future.